# How Spring boot recognize static resources in target/classes folder when build project?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, jar

I'm trying to build the React app and include it in my spring boot as a static resource.

I copied react build folder into `target/classes/public` of my spring boot project, using `maven-antrun-plugin`.

I tried both name, `target/classes/public` and `target/classes/static`.

This is my pj/target/classes structure after execute `$mvn package`

```
C:\Users\tlatl\Desktop\pj1\target\classes>tree /F
OS 볼륨에 대한 폴더 경로의 목록입니다.
볼륨 일련 번호는 722D-1A0E입니다.
C:.
│  application.properties
│
├─com
│  └─example
│      └─demo
│          │  DemoApplication.class
│          │
│          ├─controller
│          │      Controller.class
│          │      UrlRestController.class
│          │
│          ├─domain
│          │      Url.class
│          │
│          ├─repository
│          │      UrlRepository.class
│          │
│          └─service
│                  UrlService.class
│
└─public
    │  asset-manifest.json
    │  favicon.ico
    │  index.html
    │  logo192.png
    │  logo512.png
    │  manifest.json
    │  precache-manifest.5260fb84a466ee86d0bc9ba13f9afc09.js
    │  robots.txt
    │  service-worker.js
    │
    └─static
        ├─css
        │      main.500ce7b4.chunk.css
        │      main.500ce7b4.chunk.css.map
        │
        └─js
                2.c878f2b2.chunk.js
                2.c878f2b2.chunk.js.LICENSE
                2.c878f2b2.chunk.js.map
                main.1b913fda.chunk.js
                main.1b913fda.chunk.js.map
                runtime-main.e1737718.js
                runtime-main.e1737718.js.map
```

But after I execute the resulting jar file, localhost:8080 just shows a blank page.

In the blog I referred, https://blogg.kantega.no/webapp-with-create-react-app-and-spring-boot/, the writer said:

> Spring Boot applications can serve static content if you put it into the classes/public directory of the application jar file.
>
> Anything that's in the public directory on the classpath is served as a static resource by the default servlet, so you do not need to create an MVC controller for this.

So I did not set any controller with the "/" path. Other rest APIs I set are working well through the URL.

Why my spring boot does not show a static bundle in the `target/classes/public` folder?

Below is my pom.xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <node.version>v12.3.1</node.version>
        <yarn.version>v1.16.0</yarn.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.github.eirslett</groupId>
                <artifactId>frontend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.6</version>
                <configuration>
                    <workingDirectory>src/main/frontend</workingDirectory>
                    <installDirectory>target</installDirectory>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>install node and npm</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>install-node-and-npm</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <nodeVersion>v8.9.4</nodeVersion>
                            <npmVersion>5.6.0</npmVersion>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>npm install</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>npm</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <arguments>install</arguments>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>npm run build</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>npm</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <arguments>run build</arguments>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <target>
                                <copy todir="${project.build.directory}/classes/public">
                                    <fileset dir="${project.basedir}/src/main/frontend/build"/>
                                </copy>
                            </target>
                        </configuration>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>run</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>


        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: "just shows blank page" Are you sure that Spring isn't serving everything properly and that React isn't just crashing? Check your browsers console. If Spring genuinely couldn't find resources, you'd get a 404 of some kind.

Comment: @Michael React app works well when I test on dev server(localhost:3000). Console shows nothing and the page has only <html><head></head><body></body></html>.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**1.** [Spring blog](https://spring.io/blog/2013/12/19/serving-static-web-content-with-spring-boot) saying:

> Spring Boot will automatically add **static** web resources located within
> any of the following directories:

- /META-INF/resources/
- /resources/
- /static/
- /public/

Comment: The link you take reference from is from 2013. Are you sure this is still relevant?

Comment: @connexo Yes, it still valid and confirmed by https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-static-resources which is modified in 2020. + added information about configuration properties

Answer (score 2):

I would put/copy them in src/resources, the Maven build will then copy them in the application jar in the root folder

Answer (score 1):

I read the same blog and get the same issue. Just modify the config in maven-antrun-plugin:
`<copy todir="src/main/resources/static">` then it works